# c# - Pass a class to a method

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a about 80 properties in a class, i assign each value in another class. I want to put the values into a class and pass the class to a method where i save each property into a database table.

How can I do that?

EDIT:
How do I do if I want to put all the properties in a List? Do I put them in the list in the property class or in some other method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you do *what*? Make a class and pass it to a method, or take that object and persist to a database? What are you having trouble with? Edit your question, and be very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're creating what is often called a Data Transfer Object or DTO.

80 properties sounds a bit bonkers....

Apologies, I don't have my IDE handy on my Ipad, but basically something like

```
class DTO
{
//All you properties go here
}

class databaseConnector
{
     public void saveToDB (DTO dto){
      //whatever you want to do here...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about how to pass the class to a method, You need to have the class as part of the method signature and then pass your instance of the class to the method:

Method signature:

```
public void exampleMethod(YourClassName classVariable)
{
    //Do your database stuff here
}
```

Variable declaration

```
YourClassName exampleClass = new YourClassName();
```

Do what you need to with it to initialize or set variables then call your method and pass it to it:

```
exampleMethod(exampleClass);
```

Comment: When calling 'exampleMethod(exampleClass)', isn't a copy made of exampleClass? If, however, I change the method signature to 'public void exampleMethod(ref YourClassName)' then the memory location changes and no copy is never made.  Am I correct here in my understanding?

Comment: @Jim Lahman Yes that is correct, but in the case of a Class, it is a reference type, so even if it is being passed by value, you are just creating a reference to the object. If that points to the same object as the original, you can change things on the original if you aren't careful. A good article on it by Jon Skeet is at http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html